# MYSQL Query - Left join being skipped with wrong result

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Here is my SQLFiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9de13b/1

If I remove the following from the query below, it still gives the same result (in my database there is data for different years, semesters and courses):

```
 WHERE 
      Assignments.Year = '2018' 
      AND Assignments.CourseNumber = 'PHED 1164' 
      AND Assignments.Semester = 'fall' 
      AND Assignments.Assignment = 'Fitbit'
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
  c.username AS Username, 
  ROUND(
    LEAST(
      GREATEST(
        AVG(
          activities.fairly_act_min + activities.vact_min
        )/(
          (
            c.max_avgweeklymin - c.min_avgweeklymin
          )/ c.max_percent
        ), 
        AVG(activities.steps)/(
          (c.max_avgsteps - c.min_avgsteps)/ c.max_percent
        )- c.max_percent
      ), 
      100
    ), 
    1
  ) AS 'Activity Log Points Grade', 
  '#' AS 'End-of-Line Indicator' 
FROM 
  activities 
  JOIN (
    SELECT 
      Students.encodedid, 
      Students.username, 
      g.* 
    FROM 
      Assignments 
      LEFT JOIN Students ON Assignments.SectionNumber = Students.SectionNumber 
      LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
          section, 
          MAX(avgweeklymin) max_avgweeklymin, 
          MIN(avgweeklymin) min_avgweeklymin, 
          MAX(percent) max_percent, 
          MAX(avgsteps) max_avgsteps, 
          MIN(avgsteps) min_avgsteps 
        FROM 
          GradingScale 
        GROUP BY 
          section
      ) g ON Assignments.SectionNumber = g.section 
    WHERE 
      Assignments.Year = '2018' 
      AND Assignments.CourseNumber = 'PHED 1164' 
      AND Assignments.Semester = 'fall' 
      AND Assignments.Assignment = 'Fitbit'
  ) c ON activities.encodedid <> '' 
  AND activities.encodedid = c.encodedid 
  JOIN (
    SELECT 
      id, 
      encodedid, 
      GROUP_CONCAT(
        fairly_act_min + vact_min 
        ORDER BY 
          (fairly_act_min + vact_min)* 1 DESC
      ) grouped_steps 
    FROM 
      activities 
    GROUP BY 
      encodedid, 
      WEEK(
        DATE_ADD(activitydate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
      )
  ) p ON activities.id = p.id 
  AND FIND_IN_SET(
    fairly_act_min + vact_min, grouped_steps
  ) <= 5 
GROUP BY 
  c.encodedid;
```

I don't understand why my WHERE is being ignored. How can this query be rewritten to output the correct result?

Here's what I'm trying to do:
I'm tracking my students activity and steps using an activity tracker. They are assigned a weekly grade based on their activity. They are graded on their best 5 days of the week. The Steps Grade and Active Minutes Grade are based on the weekly average score of steps and active minutes. The Final Grade is based on which was higher on the grading scale between the Steps Grade and the Active Minutes Grade.

The query I've posted here is going to be run at the end of the semester to calculate each students final score.

Here is my current output:

Username,Activity Log Points Grade,End-of-Line Indicator 
mousel,44.4,#

Here is my expected output:

```
Username| Activity Log Points Grade| End-of-Line Indicator|
mousel  |        24                |         #            |
```

I hope that makes sense!

Thanks in advance,

Tim

Here is my schema:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE `activities` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `steps` mediumint(6) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `lightly_act_min` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `fairly_act_min` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `sed_act_min` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `vact_min` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `encodedid` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `activitydate` date NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `activities` (`id`, `steps`, `lightly_act_min`, `fairly_act_min`, `sed_act_min`, `vact_min`, `encodedid`, `activitydate`, `username`) VALUES
(76139, 9416, '254', '72', '642', '75', '29BD68', '2018-10-01', ''),
(106553, 0, '0', '0', '1440', '0', '29BD68', '2018-08-28', ''),
(106554, 126, '6', '0', '1434', '0', '29BD68', '2018-08-29', ''),
(106555, 9768, '257', '57', '629', '73', '29BD68', '2018-08-30', ''),
(106556, 4884, '150', '20', '865', '14', '29BD68', '2018-08-31', ''),
(106557, 7246, '170', '81', '778', '56', '29BD68', '2018-09-01', ''),
(106575, 0, '18', '5', '1018', '33', '29BD68', '2018-09-19', ''),
(106576, 65, '20', '21', '1366', '33', '29BD68', '2018-09-20', ''),
(106577, 34, '13', '3', '1331', '25', '29BD68', '2018-09-21', ''),
(106578, 18, '5', '0', '1435', '0', '29BD68', '2018-09-22', ''),
(106579, 32, '0', '0', '1440', '0', '29BD68', '2018-09-23', ''),
(106580, 6, '0', '0', '1440', '0', '29BD68', '2018-09-24', ''),
(106581, 10320, '251', '121', '585', '34', '29BD68', '2018-09-25', ''),
(106582, 5974, '236', '32', '723', '3', '29BD68', '2018-09-26', ''),
(106583, 8455, '239', '47', '733', '27', '29BD68', '2018-09-27', ''),
(106584, 6262, '204', '71', '765', '10', '29BD68', '2018-09-28', ''),
(123953, 40, '1', '0', '1439', '0', '29BD68', '2018-11-11', ''),
(123954, 639, '48', '0', '1392', '0', '29BD68', '2018-11-12', ''),
(123955, 5878, '270', '76', '485', '36', '29BD68', '2018-11-13', ''),
(123956, 7485, '330', '81', '1014', '15', '29BD68', '2018-11-14', ''),
(123957, 5372, '270', '53', '545', '0', '29BD68', '2018-11-15', ''),
(124888, 4699, '214', '12', '825', '6', '29BD68', '2018-11-16', ''),
(125819, 0, '2', '0', '1438', '0', '29BD68', '2018-11-17', ''),
(126750, 0, '0', '0', '1440', '0', '29BD68', '2018-11-18', ''),
(129533, 5070, '279', '14', '728', '14', '29BD68', '2018-11-19', ''),
(129534, 6471, '256', '124', '657', '15', '29BD68', '2018-11-20', ''),
(129535, 3475, '144', '9', '722', '29', '29BD68', '2018-11-21', ''),
(131405, 232, '16', '0', '965', '0', '29BD68', '2018-11-22', ''),
(131406, 3546, '135', '1', '791', '18', '29BD68', '2018-11-23', ''),
(133276, 6143, '278', '71', '657', '24', '29BD68', '2018-11-24', '');

ALTER TABLE `activities`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `encodedid` (`encodedid`,`activitydate`) USING BTREE;

ALTER TABLE `activities`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=230103;
COMMIT;

CREATE TABLE `Assignments` (
  `AssignmentID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Assignment` enum('Fitbit','Written Paper','Fitness Assessment') NOT NULL,
  `PointsPossible` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `CourseNumber` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  `SectionNumber` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `Semester` enum('Fall','Spring','Summer1','Summer2','Winter','May') NOT NULL,
  `Year` year(4) NOT NULL,
  `PreStartDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `PreEndDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `PostStartDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `PostEndDate` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `Assignments` (`AssignmentID`, `Assignment`, `PointsPossible`, `CourseNumber`, `SectionNumber`, `Semester`, `Year`, `PreStartDate`, `PreEndDate`, `PostStartDate`, `PostEndDate`) VALUES
(47, 'Fitbit', 100, 'PHED 1164', '5073', 'Fall', 2018, '2018-09-03 00:00:00', '2018-12-07 23:30:00', '2018-09-03 00:00:00', '2018-12-07 23:30:00'),
(48, 'Fitbit', 100, 'PHED 1164', '5075', 'Fall', 2018, '2018-09-03 00:00:00', '2018-12-07 23:30:00', '2018-09-03 00:00:00', '2018-12-07 23:30:00'),
(49, 'Fitbit', 100, 'PHED 1164', '5019', 'Fall', 2018, '2018-09-03 00:00:00', '2018-12-12 23:30:00', '2018-09-03 00:00:00', '2018-12-12 23:30:00'),
(61, 'Fitness Assessment', 100, 'PHED 1164', '5087', 'Fall', 2018, '2018-09-23 00:00:00', '2018-10-01 23:30:00', '2018-11-30 00:00:00', '2018-12-07 23:30:00');

ALTER TABLE `Assignments`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`AssignmentID`);
ALTER TABLE `Assignments` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `section_number_index` (`SectionNumber`);

ALTER TABLE `Assignments`
  MODIFY `AssignmentID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=91;
COMMIT;

CREATE TABLE `Students` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `SectionNumber` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `first` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `last` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `semester` enum('fall','spring','summer1','summer2','winterminimester','mayminimester') NOT NULL,
  `year` year(4) NOT NULL,
  `CourseNumber` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  `passtext` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `created` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` enum('y','n') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'y',
  `visitorIP` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `aboutme` text NOT NULL,
  `age` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `regkey` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `goal_start` date NOT NULL,
  `goal` enum('muscle','weight','perform','toning') NOT NULL,
  `encodedid` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `accesstoken` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
  `accesstoken_expiry` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `refreshtoken` varchar(2000) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `Students` (`id`, `SectionNumber`, `first`, `last`, `username`, `semester`, `year`, `CourseNumber`, `passtext`, `email`, `created`, `active`, `visitorIP`, `aboutme`, `age`, `regkey`, `goal_start`, `goal`, `encodedid`, `accesstoken`, `accesstoken_expiry`, `refreshtoken`) VALUES
(8, '5075', 'Tim', 'Mousel', 'mousel', 'fall', 2018, 'PHED 1164', '$2y$12$FDSvsMUpSQ79THcC6eCij.YjDFbwGQhHozvcJVa81tD4oYKAyrRi2', 'mousel@defend.net', '2018-03-26', 'y', '99.165.89.33', '', '', '8630082118400458833008407', '0000-00-00', 'muscle', '29BD68', 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIyMkNWWkYiLCJzdWIiOiIyOUJENjgiLCJpc3MiOiJGaXRiaXQiLCJ0eXAiOiJhY2Nlc3NfdG9rZW4iLCJzY29wZXMiOiJyd2VpIHJhY3QgcmhyIHJwcm8gcm51dCIsImV4cCI6MTU0ODA1NjI0MywiaWF0IjoxNTQ4MDI3NDQzfQ.K5Pag0_4EfME21I5aUrPqwPE-otPQH458jidDl1FvgM', '2019-01-21 07:37:23', '1498d6c65ceaa43daf5a40db4af60a16a9cb37b96d86de3635c1a4ff89723574');

ALTER TABLE `Students`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `Students` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `encodedid_index` (`encodedid`);

ALTER TABLE `Students`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=459;
COMMIT;

CREATE TABLE `GradingScale` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `letter` enum('A','B','C','D','F') NOT NULL,
  `percent` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  `avgsteps` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `avgweeklymin` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  `section` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `AssignmentID` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Grading Scale';


INSERT INTO `GradingScale` (`id`, `letter`, `percent`, `avgsteps`, `avgweeklymin`, `section`, `AssignmentID`) VALUES
(1101, 'A', 100, 10000, 100, '5075', 1),
(1102, 'A', 90, 9500, 90, '5075', 1),
(1103, 'B', 80, 9000, 80, '5075', 1),
(1104, 'C', 70, 8500, 70, '5075', 1),
(1105, 'D', 60, 8000, 60, '5075', 1),
(1106, 'F', 50, 7500, 50, '5075', 1),
(1107, 'F', 40, 7000, 40, '5075', 1),
(1108, 'F', 30, 6500, 30, '5075', 1),
(1109, 'F', 20, 6000, 20, '5075', 1),
(1110, 'F', 10, 5500, 10, '5075', 1),
(1111, 'F', 0, 5000, 0, '5075', 1);

ALTER TABLE `GradingScale`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `section` (`section`,`percent`,`letter`) USING BTREE;
```

Comment: Much better to show your expected output.

Comment: I think it's a mistake to store non-integer semesters here.

Comment: And I never even knew a year data type existed! I wouldn't use it. What's the point?

Comment: @VijunavVastivch - I added my current and expected output, thank you

Comment: @Strawberry - Since the semesters are fall, spring,etc., why is it a mistake to store them as non-integers?  I'm using the year data type because I only need to know the year they are enrolled and it takes up only 1-byte. What is your recommendation? Thanks, I remember you helped me once before. :)

Comment: By implication, the solution is to store integer semesters, with a link to a separate table which stores 'fall', etc.

Comment: You output is not clear to your script. You have to give on how to do the put you wanted something like `thisfield/anotherfield + anything`